# How would I use Curl to download only URLs in a specific directory when using macOS?

Tags: mac, curl

This applies to `https://www.gocaravanning.com/caravan-specs/Swift-Caravan-Data.html`; I want to download all the years' linked to and ***only*** those pages.

I know `curl -O` downloads the files.

Would the command be:

```
User@MacbookPro mydir curl -O https://www.gocaravanning.com/caravan-specs/Swift-[YEAR]-Caravan-Info.html
```

Note that `mydir` is on the Desktop

It doesn’t matter that there's no CSS etc; it’s just downloading the info within the directory

If anyone can help I’d appreciate this; been learning basic Curl.

Answer (score 0):

> Would the command be:
>
> ```
> User@MacbookPro mydir curl -O https://www.gocaravanning.com/caravan-specs/Swift-[YEAR]-Caravan-Info.html
> ```

For what I believe your purposes are, essentially yes. Looking at the [official `curl` manpage reference](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html), to download each HTML page with the format:

```
 Swift-[YEAR]-Caravan-Info.html
```

You can use `[]` to provide the relevant start and end "years" to use in each URL:

```
curl -O https://www.gocaravanning.com/caravan-specs/Swift-[1990-2016]-Caravan-Info.html
```

---

*Be aware that this doesn't actually extract links from the page. It simply makes consecutive direct requests for e.g. `Swift-1990-Caravan-Info.html`, `Swift-1991-Caravan-Info.html`, `Swift-1992-Caravan-Info.html`, etc.*

---